# How adds the specified image to the user’s Camera Roll album on MonoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

To add the specified image to the user’s Camera Roll album in Obj-C can use [UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum) method.

What is equivalent on MonoTouch or how can i do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` function maps to [`UIImage.SaveToPhotosAlbum`](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage.SaveToPhotosAlbum%28MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage.SaveStatus%29).

Craig has a [sample](http://conceptdev.blogspot.ca/2009/10/monotouch-screen-capture-in-c-code.html) showing how to use this API on his blog.

**EDIT**: The simple sample code: (photo is `UIImage`)

```
photo.SaveToPhotosAlbum((image, error) => {
    if (error == null)
        new UIAlertView("", "Saved", null, "OK", null).Show();
    else
        new UIAlertView("", "Failed", null, "OK", null).Show();
});
```